# Extracting subscripts and superscripts

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose I have several types of expressions (in some random order) of the form

`Power[Subscript[g, a], μ]` which is $g_a{}^\mu$

`Subscript[Power[g, a], α]]` which is $g^a{}_\alpha$

`Power[g, Times[ρ, θ]]` which is $g^{\rho\theta}$

`Subscript[Subscript[g, a], α]` which is $g_{a \alpha}$

I need to extract subscript and superscript regardless of the type of the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exprs = {Power[Subscript[g, a], μ ], Subscript[Power[g, a], α ],
         Power[g, Times[ρ, θ] ], Subscript[Subscript[g, a], α] }

Cases[#, (Power | Subscript)[_, y_] :> y, {0, Infinity}]&/@ exprs
(* {{a, μ}, {a, α}, {θ ρ}, {a, α}} *)
```

Update: To get separate lists of powers and subscripts:

```
{powers, subscripts} = Function[{head}, Cases[#, head[_, y_] :> y, {0, Infinity}] & /@ exprs] /@ 
                       {Power, Subscript}
(* {{{μ}, {a}, {θ ρ}, {}}, {{a}, {α}, {}, {a, α}}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But in this case $g_{ab}$ and $g^{ab}$ give the same output $\{a b\}$. They should be distinguishable

Comment: @g3n1uss, please see the update.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify an output format.  Nevertheless I propose:

```
f[b_^su_ | Subscript[b_, sb_]] :=
  Join[f@b, {Up[su], Down[sb]}] ~Cases~ _[_]

f[else_] := {}
```

Example:

```
test = {
  Power[Subscript[g, a], μ],
  Subscript[Power[g, a], α],
  Power[g, Times[ρ, θ]],
  Subscript[Subscript[g, a], α]
 };

f /@ test
```

> ```
> {{Down[a], Up[μ]}, {Up[a], Down[α]}, {Up[θ ρ]}, {Down[a], Down[α]}}
> ```

Up and Down serve to label superscripts and subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

I propose to use a custom structure

```
add[{a___}, (List | Times)[b___] | c_] := {b, c, a}
script[a_^b_, sub_: {}, sup_: {}] := script[a, sub, add[sup, b]];
script[Subscript[a_, b_], sub_: {}, sup_: {}] := script[a, add[sub, b], sup];

script /@ exprs
(*{script[g, {a}, {μ}], script[g, {α}, {a}], script[g, {}, {θ, ρ}], script[g, {a, α}, {}]}*)
```

It is very clear and allows you further pattern-matching and other abilities.

Also you can add custom formatting

```
script /: MakeBoxes[script[g_, sub_, sup_], StandardForm] := 
 SubsuperscriptBox[ToBoxes@g, RowBox[ToBoxes /@ sub], RowBox[ToBoxes /@ sup]]
```

to display the result as

[image]